# Understanding and Converting Ruby's ChunkyPNG to Javascript Equivalent

Tags: javascript, ruby, chunkypng, pngjs

I am converting some RUBY code into Javascript.
This RUBY code uses ChunkyPNG Ruby Library.

Here is the Ruby Code:

```
def self.from_png(file)
  image = ChunkyPNG::Image.from_file(file)
  mask = Mask.new(image.height, image.width)

  mask.rows.times do |row|
    mask.columns.times do |col|
      if image[col, row] == ChunkyPNG::Color::BLACK
        mask[row, col] = false
      else
        mask[row, col] = true
      end
    end
  end

  mask
end
```

How to convert the above code to Javascript?
The 2 lines I am facing challenges with converting are:

```
image = ChunkyPNG::Image.from_file(file)
```

and

```
if image[col, row] == ChunkyPNG::Color::BLACK
```

What Javascript PNG library can I use to do the same?

What does

```
image[col, row]
```

refer to? is it RG in RGB?? or what is it?  Understanding this can help me find the equivalent Javascript method in Javascript PNG Libraries ...

Comment: Must be color, probably number by comparision - image[col, row] == ChunkyPNG::Color::BLACK looks like black background(?) is used as transparent background around image ? It is number - here https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png/blob/master/lib/chunky_png/color.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image[col, row]` refers to specific pixel of the image at position (col, row).
Image can be described as 2D array of colors - in this case, color is an instance of `ChunkyPNG::Color` or just a number. In your code sample all black pixels marked as `false` in the mask, all non-black marked as `true`.